# How to prevent pods scheduling to a node after a pod has failed on it, in GCE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a setup with 1 to 1 mapping between pods and nodes, where each node has a local ssd, and each pod writes custom data to that ssd.  If a pod dies ungracefully, it can leave the local ssd in a state where it'd be unpredictable if other pods mounted onto it.

I'm planning on using cluster auto scaling, so my thinking is that if I can prevent containers being scheduled on the node, GCE will remove the node, and create a new clean one?  How do I go about preventing the node having new pods scheduled to it?

Answer (score 1):

I would run a scheduled task (probably [cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)) that checks the volume state. If the voulme is corrupted - add a [label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) to the node - (for example - `volume-state=corrupted` )

Schedule your Pod with [nodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature) - `requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution` and nodeSelector by your label

> it will evict pods from nodes that cease to satisfy the pods’ node affinity requirements.